# How to show Snackbar above FloatingActionBar (fab) placed on Bottom App Bar (Material design)

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I was trying out the new material Bottom App bar. In design guidelines it's told "Inset a snackbar or toast above a bottom app bar and FAB" but I'm not sure to how to do it. Can anyone help me. Below are the codes that I'm using:

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show());
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />
```

**gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

The problem is that whenever I click the `fab` button the snackbar appears above the bottom app bar and also pushes the fab above. Below is the image for the problem.

[image: material design snackbar plroblem]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114481413) which has been fixed. There's a new API `setAnchorView` which, I think, we will be getting on next update; for detail, head to: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/868e80ed6ff183cceeb9c33523bf47f72772c52a

Answer (score 5):

Please use the setAnchorView() Method :-

```
Snackbar.make(CoordinatorLayoutView, "your text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAnchorView(BottomAppBarView or FabButtonView).show();
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and use *Code Sample* for greater readability.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the latest Material library:

Edit build.gradle (module: app) and update material:1.0.0 to 1.1.0-alpha04 or the latest:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a layout ID to your `content_main` layout so you can obtain a reference to it in your activity code via `findViewById`
2. Instead of passing the fab view, use the content_main's layout view in Snackbar.make(**view**)

That should make your snackbar appear above the BottomAppBar.

Comment: To make this answer complete, check [this example](https://github.com/firatkarababa/BottomAppBarBehaviour) for that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll be testing it, it the meantime, can you guys help me to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575148/bottom-app-bar-show-hide-on-interacting-with-fragments-navigation-architecture